# Can someone explain for me this remainder?

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying really hard to understand `if ((x + y) % 2 == 0)`... I can't understand the logic behind it.

```
var drawTable = "";
var size = 8;

for (x = 1; x <= size; x++) {
    for (y = 1; y <= size; y++) {
        if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) {
            drawTable += " ";
        } else {
            drawTable += "#";
        }
    }
    drawTable += "\n"
}

console.log(drawTable);
```

Thanks,

Kaue Pacheco

Comment: `(x + y) % 2 === 0` iff. `x + y` is even.

Comment: the logic is, that if x+y is even add a space, if it's odd add a # ... %2 can either be 0 or 1 ... if it's 1, the number is odd (because n / 2 has a remainder of 1 for odd numbers)

Comment: [MDN Remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder)

Answer (score 1):

`if ((x + y) % 2 == 0)` is the same as `if (x + y) is an even number`.

Answer (score 1):

`((x + y) % 2 == 0)`  is true only when `x+y` is even, otherwise it is false.
If is true it will add a space otherwise it will add # symbol.

Answer (score 1):

It goes to show if the sum of x and y is an even number. If x=1 and y=3, then x+y will be 4 and 4 will be divided. If it has a 0 remainder (like the number 4 does), it is an even number. Else, it is an odd number.

Your code will only execute the content inside the if condition of ((x+y)%2==0) if your remainder is zero. Hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 0):

As all of the other answers have stated, if `x+y` is even, it will print out a space, and if it is odd, it will print out a '#'. The point of that appears to be to create a checkerboard pattern. Since you will start off with x = 1 and y = 1, the first line will be started with a space (since x+y is even), followed by a '#', followed by a space... until y is 9. Then the inner for loop will be exited and a new line started. On this new line x will start out at 2 and y at 1, so a '#' will be printed (since x+y is odd) followed by a space followed by... until y is 8 again. Then a new line will be started and that will continue until x is 9. At that point a checkerboard will be printed out.

Answer (score 0):

*if ((x + y) % 2 == 0)* if you want a further explanation of this.

the modulo '`%`' is use to get the remainder of the division.

if you have for example:

```
5 % 2 = ?
```

In this scenario, It will divide 5 by 2. now the answer would be its `remainder` and not the `quotient`.

so the answer would be:

```
5 % 2 = 1
```

you will know if it is an `even` or `odd` number because you divided 5 by 2, and the remainder will distinguish whether it is an even or odd number by comparing it to `0`. Obviously, all that equals to **0** are **Even Numbers**.